# Paradox regarding the size of real numbers?

Tags: infinity, paradoxes

Suppose you want to represent numbers in base 9, so digits 0 to 8. You can express any real number in base 9, so this set is uncountably infinite.

However, it can be shown that in base 10, the likelihood of any real number containing a 9 approaches 100%, meaning that the numbers not containing 9 are insignificant, approaching 0%, to those that do. E.g. similar to this proof using 7, https://www.flyingcoloursmaths.co.uk/percentage-numbers-seven/

However, this set of numbers not containing 9 is identical to those numbers expressed in base 9. So we have an uncountable infinite set (real numbers in base 9) being 0% of the size of another uncountable infinite set (real numbers in base 10).

This can continue, real numbers in base 8 vs real numbers in base 9, real numbers in base 7 vs real numbers in base 8, etc. As well in the other direction, real numbers in base 10 vs real numbers in base 11, and so on.

Basically, considering only natural numbers as bases, there are a countable infinity of uncountable infinities!

Comment: Yes, but what is your question?

Comment: One of your statements is about measure theory (e.g. the set of real numbers avoiding 9 in their base 10 representation has measure zero), while others are about cardinality, or even order (base $i$ strings as base $i+1$ strings).

All of your infinities are the same "size" (cardinality) but different "sizes" (measures) depending on how you relate them (e.g. viewing base 9 strings as base 10 strings).

Comment: @yoyo - Interesting, was not aware of cardinality vs measure. So the cardinalities are all ℵ1 because there is a one-to-one correspondence among them, but the sizes can be different because of how they are grouped, like manipulating a geometric series to generate any desired result.

Comment: Also note that regardless of the base in which they are represented, there is only one set of real numbers. So what you have shown is various ways to construct an injection from the set of real numbers to itself.

Comment: "so this set is uncountably infinite"  Which set do you mean?

Comment: " the likelihood of any real number containing a 9 approaches 100%" — It is not at all clear what you mean by "approaches".

Comment: The cardinalities referred to are **not** known to be aleph_1, because that depends on the undecidable Continuum Hypothesis. What *is* known is that the cardinalities are 2^(aleph_0), otherwise known as the continuum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically all these sets are the same size:

- numbers with nines
- numbers without nines
- numbers expressed in base nine

That's how infinity works. For example, using a countable infinity, you can generate a one-to-one correspondence between the integers and numbers containing **only** the digit nine:

```
1      9
2     99
3    999
4   9999
5  99999
...
n  10ⁿ-1
```

If you were to take any N numbers, I think you would agree that those containing only nines are much rarer than the rest, so their frequency would approach 0%, even with a one-to-one correspondence with the integers.